# Can have low curb close to side of toilet?

Tags: plumbing

[image]I’m adding a half bath to a finished attic. There is a 9 inch high, 1 foot deep boxed in duct next to where I’d like to put the toilet. Does the toilet have to be 15 inches from this 9 inch high box (it’s below the height of toilet seat), or can I start the 15 inches at the wall? See photo. The pink marks 15 inches from the box. I would prefer to have it where the level is so I have more room for a vanity.

Comment: Photo would help...but the 15” is “clear” floor space from the center of the toilet to the wall or obstruction (cabinet, etc.)

Comment: Even if the obstruction is only 9 inches high? It is too low to interfere with use of the toilet.

Comment: Is it?  Once the toilet is in place, can you sit on it, or stand in front of it, and not have your foot, shin or calf bang into the box?

Comment: Is this a code question, a future cleaning question, or a "how will it feel" question?  For the feel question get a box just that size and put it next to an existing toilet.  For a code question, check with your inspector -- there can be flexibility.

Comment: Have you thought about moving the location to the left and putting the toilet in at a 45, this is how I have made room in the past with areas that did not have clearance at a 90.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 15” is required from the center of the toilet to the wall/cabinet.

However, you could raise the toilet 9” to the top of the curb...a true throne.

Be sure to maintain a 6’-8” ceiling height. (Most rooms require a 7’ ceiling height, but there is an exception in the code for bathrooms. See IRC R305.)

Answer (score 0):

It is 15" from wall or cabinet but yet your little box is neither.   Unless inspector is very liberal with the code you are fine.   Put toilet down and sit on it.   If you are a comfortable distance from the box - couple inches - and it seems good, then install it.

If you are getting a permit, just ask inspector beforehand and mention that code is cabinet or wall.   If the "box" is below toilet height and doesn't extend out to depth of toilet I see zero issue here.